# How to approximate $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^3 + x}$ for $x$ approaching $\infty$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

How to find the approximate value of $f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^3 + x}$ as a function of $x$ when $x$ goes to $\infty$? I want a closed form function $g(x)$ s.t. $f(x) \sim g(x) $ for $x \to \infty$.

I have tried to integrate $f(x)$:
$$ \int f(x) dx= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n\int\frac{1}{n^3 + x} dx = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n \log(n^3 + x).$$ But this isn't helpful. Any other idea?

Comment: To get leading behavior of the sum, approximate  the sum by a integral over $n$, this is essentially the second part of Eric's answer. If you need more terms for an  asymptotic expansion, use the relation
$$\frac{n}{n^3+y^3} = -\frac{1}{3y}\left(\frac{1}{n+y} + \frac{1}{\omega(n + y\omega)} + \frac{1}{\bar{\omega}(n + y\bar{\omega})}\right)$$
where $y = x^{1/3}$ and $\omega = e^{2\pi i/3}$ to express your sum in terms of [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) and use digamma's asymptotic expansion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we want to find several first asymptotic terms, the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) is probably a shortcut to the answer:
$$\sum_{n=a}^{n=b}f(n)\sim\int_a^bf(x)dx+\frac12\big(f(b)+f(a)\big)+\frac1{12}\big(f'(b)-f'(a)\big)+...$$
where all other terms are odd derivatives of $f(x)$, taken on the bounds.

In our case $\displaystyle S(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac n{n^3+x}$, and the bounds are $\,a=0; \,b=\infty$. As we have only odd derivatives in the sum, analysis shows that  the third surviving term $\sim\frac1{x^3}$

Therefore,
$$S(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac t{t^3+x}dt-\frac1{12\,x}+O\Big(\frac1{x^3}\Big)\tag{1}$$
The evaluation of the integral is straightforward:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac t{t^3+x}dt\overset{t=sx^{-1/3}}{=}x^{-1/3}\int_0^\infty \frac s{1+s^3}ds\overset{s^3=t}{=}\frac1{3x^{1/3}}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{-1/3}}{1+t}dt$$
Making the substitution $s=\frac1{1+t}$ we are getting Beta-function
$$=\frac1{3x^{1/3}}\int_0^1(1-s)^{-1/3}s^{-2/3}ds$$
Using the Euler formula for Gamma-function
$$=\frac1{3x^{1/3}}\Gamma\Big(\frac13\Big)\Gamma\Big(\frac23\Big)=\frac1{3x^{1/3}}\frac\pi{\sin\frac\pi3}=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}\frac1{x^{1/3}}\tag{2}$$
Putting (2) into (1)
$$\boxed{\,\,S(x)=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}\frac1{x^{1/3}}-\frac1{12}\frac1x+O\Big(\frac1{x^3}\Big)\,\,}$$

---

Numeric check with WA for $x=10$

$\displaystyle S(10)=0.55294...$

$\displaystyle \left(\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}\frac1{x^{1/3}}-\frac1{12}\frac1x\right)\,\bigg|_{x=10}=0.552927...$

Comment: Thank you for sharing this powerful Euler-Maclaurin formula. Although I have taken calculus, this is totally new to me.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the comments, we can express $f(x)$ in terms of the [digamma function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7.E6) $\psi(x)$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \frac{1}{{3x^{1/3} }}\left( {\psi (x^{1/3}  + 1) + {\rm e}^{ - 2\pi {\rm i}/3} \psi (x^{1/3} {\rm e}^{2\pi {\rm i}/3}  + 1) + {\rm e}^{2\pi {\rm i}/3} \psi (x^{1/3} {\rm e}^{ - 2\pi {\rm i}/3}  + 1)} \right)
\\ & = \frac{1}{{3x^{1/3} }}\left( {\psi (x^{1/3}  + 1) + 2\operatorname{Re} \left( {{\rm e}^{ - 2\pi {\rm i}/3} \psi (x^{1/3} {\rm e}^{2\pi {\rm i}/3}  + 1)} \right)} \right).
\end{align*}
By applying the [standard asymptotic expansion](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11.E2) of the digamma function and simplifying the result, we obtain the complete asymptotic expansion
$$
f(x) \sim \frac{{2\pi }}{{3\sqrt 3 }}\frac{1}{{x^{1/3} }} - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{B_{6k + 2} }}{{6k + 2}}\frac{1}{{x^{2k + 1} }}}  = \frac{{2\pi }}{{3\sqrt 3 }}\frac{1}{{x^{1/3} }} - \frac{1}{{12x}} + \frac{1}{{240x^3 }} - \frac{1}{{12x^5 }} +  \ldots ,
$$
as $x\to+\infty$. Here, $B_k$ denotes the [Bernoulli numbers](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.2.i). This is in agreement with the result given by @Svyatoslav.

**Addendum.** An expansion valid for $-1< x < 8$ is
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{{1 + x}} + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^k (\zeta (3k + 2) - 1)x^k } ,
$$
where $\zeta$ is the [Riemann zeta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2).

Comment: thank you for your solution! As usual - a complete asymptotics obtained :)

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches:

The trickiness here is that the $n^3$ term goes from not mattering to mattering. We can estimate each regime separately by breaking up the sum into before and after $x^{1/3}$

Approximately, the first part is $$\sum^{x^{1/3}}_{n=1} \frac{n}{n^3+x}\approx 
\sum^{x^{1/3}}_{n=1} \frac{n}{x} \approx x^{-1/3}/2$$

The second part is approximately:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n= x^{1/3}} \frac{n}{n^3+x}\approx 
\sum^{\infty}_{n= x^{1/3}} \frac{n}{n^3} \approx 
\sum^{\infty}_{n= x^{1/3}} \frac{1}{n^2} \approx x^{-1/3}$$

Combining gives an overestimate of $\frac{3}{2 x^{1/3}}$. This is off by at most a factor of $2$ given our haphazard handling of dropping the smaller term, especially near $n=x^{1/3}$.

The second approach is to compute $\int^\infty_0 y/(y^3+x)dy$. Substitution gives that it’s proportional to $x^{1/3}$, and substituting $x=1$ and using Wolfram Alpha gives that the constant is actually $\frac{2\sqrt{3}\pi}{9}\approx 1.21$ which matches with the above overestimate constant of $1.5$.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing these two solutions. Both of them are very insightful!